# Focus of a parabola, without derivatives

Tags: geometry, functions, conic-sections

I have a seemingly easy question, but I have no clue how to find out its answer.
I have the function

$$f(x)=\tfrac{1}{8} x^2$$

This function is for (a parabolic cross-section through) a paraboloid and I am searching for the point where, when this point emits light, every lightwave is parallel after reflection in the paraboloid.

I know the solution is the point $P(0;2)$ but I have no clue why.
The problem I have is that I have no way of using derivatives for this, otherwise it would be fairly easy. I hope you can help me…

Comment: If the parabola is written on paper, its burning point should be $451^\circ$ Fahrenheit

Comment: The direction of reflected rays is determined by the normal of the surface. How do you define the normal of a function's graph without using derivatives?

Comment: uhm, that was my problem as well.. i am currently in year 12 in school and it was from an exam from year 10, and they have no chance of using derivatives, so i have to give this exception :D

Comment: Presumably, in order to answer this question in high-school, you would use a formula to find the [focus of a parabola](http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/focus-of-a-parabola.html) that was previously given.  Of course, doing this for some arbitrary curve would require calculus.

Comment: Hannes, the point you are looking for is the focus of the paraboloid.

Comment: Oh :D i am no native english speaker, sorry :D but thank you, i already thought about that... mmmh, thank you anyways :D but is there another solution with university maths?

Comment: “…another solution with university maths?”: Well, using complex numbers and projective geometry, you could construct the tangents to the parabola through the ideal circle points with homogeneous coordinates $(1,\pm i,0)$. One common tangent would be the line at infinity, while the other two would intersect in the focus. The tangents you'd get by first computing the polar line, which is a simple matrix multiplication, and then intersecting that line with the conic, so there are no derivatives involved. But all of this is *way* beyond 10th grade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go in reverse. If you have the directrix at $y=-f$ and focus at $(x_f,y_f)=(0,f)$, then you can write down the definition of parabola:

$$||(x,y)-(0,f)||=y-(-f)$$
Square this:
$$x^2+(y-f)^2=(y+f)^2$$
$$x^2=4yf$$
$$y=\frac{x^2}{4f}$$